# Can we access all data columns in a custom ggplot2's stat?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, survival-analysis, ggproto

I would like to implement diagnostics for Cox proportional hazards model with `ggplot2`, by creating new `stats` functions and `ggproto` objects. The idea is to benefit from grouping (by `color`, `facet_grid`, etc.) for conditional computation of desired statistics (e.g. martingale residuals).
In the example below, the null model is refitted and martingale's computed for each cofactor level. The issues are:

1. Fit is done based on `data` argument provided internally for the `ggproto`'s `compute_group` method, not the actual dataset. This means, that dataframe is stripped of columns not explicitly defined in `aes` so it's up to the user to provide at least "time to event" and "event indicator" columns each time. (unless they're hardcoded in a wrappper for `stat_...` function). **Can `compute_group` somehow access corresponding rows from the original dataset?**
2. Rownames for `compute_group`'s `data` are unique per `PANEL`, which means they do not reflect the actual rownames of original dataset supplited to `ggplot`, and we can no longer exclude e.g. incomplete cases omitted by full model, unless explicitly specifying/hardcoding some id variable. **The question is same as above.**
3. **Can a `geom` layer access the `y`'s computed by another custom stat, which is also plotted?** Consider a scatterplot of residuals with a smoother, such as. `ggplot(data, aes(x = covariate, time = time, event = event)) + stat_funcform() + geom_smooth(aes(y = ..martingales..))`, where `..martingales..` are actually computed by `stat_funcform`.

.

```
# Load & Set data ---------------------------------------------------------

require(data.table)
require(dplyr)
require(ggplot2)
require(survival)
set.seed(1)

dt <- data.table(factor = sample(c(0, 2), 1e3, T),
                 factor2 = sample(c(0, 2, NA), 1e3, T),
                 covariate = runif(1e3, 0, 1))
dt[, `:=`(etime = rexp(1e3, .01 * (.5 + factor + covariate)),
          ctime = runif(1e3, 0, 1e2))]
dt[, `:=`(event = ifelse(etime < ctime, 1, 0),
          time = ifelse(etime < ctime, etime, ctime))]
survfit(Surv(time, event) ~ factor + I(covariate > .5), data = dt) %>% 
  autoplot(fun = 'cloglog')


# Fit coxph model ---------------------------------------------------------

fit <- coxph(Surv(time, event) ~ factor + covariate, data = dt)

# Define custom stat ------------------------------------------------------

StatFuncform <- ggproto(
  "StatFuncform", Stat,
  compute_group = function(data, scales, params) {
    head(data) %>% print
    data$y <- update(params$fit, ~ 1, data = data) %>% 
      resid(type = 'martingale')

    return(data)
  }
)

stat_funcform <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, geom = "point",
                          position = "identity", na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA, 
                          inherit.aes = TRUE, ...) {
  layer(
    stat = StatFuncform, data = data, mapping = mapping, geom = geom, 
    position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params = list(na.rm = na.rm, ...)
  )
}


# Plot --------------------------------------------------------------------

# computation unsuccessfull - no 'time' and 'event' variables    
ggplot(data = dt, 
       mapping = aes(x = covariate, 
                     color = factor(event))) + 
  stat_funcform(params = list(fit = fit)) + 
  facet_grid(~ factor, labeller = label_both, margins = TRUE)

# ok - 'time' and 'event' specified explicitly    
ggplot(data = dt, 
       mapping = aes(x = covariate, time = time, event = event, 
                     factor2 = factor2,
                     color = factor(event))) + 
  stat_funcform(params = list(fit = fit)) + 
  facet_grid(~ factor, labeller = label_both, margins = TRUE)
```

I'm aware there are already a few packages implementing diagnostics for survival analysis (e.g. `survminer`) or `ggplot2`'s  `autoplot` methods, but they're rather providing wrappers instead of taking advantage of default `ggplot2() + stat_` semantics.

Comment: I didn't get any error message. I did get a warning: "Computation failed in `stat_funcform()`: Time variable is not numeric"

Comment: I've edited the comment. This might be the way ggplot handles error in `stat`'s computations. Nevertheless, the plot is not produced, and message  is probably a result of accessing `time` function, instead of variable, due to scoping order.

Comment: After a bit of research, as far as I'am concerned, there are no special/environmental variables, that would allow to access the original data and/or preserve the row mapping. 
Also, the data is computed per layer, arguments are defined pretty explicitly, and methods involved during the printing procedure are supplied with individual layers, instead of the complete `ggplot` object.

Comment: I think, that the whole difficulty arises from the fact, that data is expected to be precomputed as data.frame, when the `ggplot` object is created (`fortify`, etc.), while the whole `stat`, `facet`, `aesthetics` logic kicks in while printing the object. 
I guess what I need is to move the data creation/evaluation step towards the printing. Some possibilities are: 1) insert an additional method called between `ggplot()` and `print()`; 2) construct wrapper around `ggplot.print`, 3) modify `ggplot2:::Layer$compute_layer()` function to take the whole plot as a parameter